# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() with mysqlnd installed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

Basically, I have noticed other people have had a similar issue but they haven't had Mysqlnd installed.

Yet i still get this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in...

Yet I have the necessary drivers installed and it works beautifully on my local host.

[image]

Anybody know what the issue is? I'm using 1and1 webhosting with Linux.

Comment: What version of PHP is installed?

Comment: PHP 5.4 is currently installed.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Someone else is having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518255/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result-mysqlnd-is-enabled?noredirect=1#comment32488860_21518255

Comment: Your picture doesn't say anything about mysqli. Apparently, only PDO is available.

Comment: This issue is just major hassle unless your running a webserver on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue at the moment.

Is mysqlnd installed or is it not installed, that is the question.

Notice under "API EXTENSIONS" in your screenshot (last entry) it only lists `PDO_mysql`. It should also list `mysql,mysqli,` like it does on my server where it works.

BUT... is that the problem? I'm trying to get mysqli to run on a seperate server with **WHM/cpanel**, and after following all 'standard' setup steps i'm left with the question of whether mysqlnd is installed or not.

Doing a `class_exists()` check confirms the "mysqli" is now available. So it must be installed, just like phpinfo() says, no?

Well... yes and no. You can now connect to the database with the `mysqli connector` and you can prepare statements, and you can execute normal mysql functions, but NOT mysqli ones... like  `get_result()`

Doing a `class_exists()` check on "mysqli_stmt" confirms the class exists (yay, its installed??)... but when you list the methods of the class  `get_class_methods('mysqli_stmt')`  you will strangely find that all normal mysqli methods like  get_result() are NOT available. According to `php.net` they SHOULD be there.

So whats the problem and how to fix it?

I wish i knew.

My solution for now: Rewrite the statements in PDO style. :-(

Comment: Yeah, I've written a set of PDO classes. Was far quicker and works like a charm.